# Attaching maven-exec-plugin to initialize

Tags: java, maven, clojure

I am trying to attach an exec process to a maven build. I want to build a secondary dependency (that is actually a Clojure project build with maven) every time I build the maven project.

Currently, I have the `pom.xml` below, but the exec process is just not running. The maven documentation is not that much help.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>compile-with-lein</id>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <executable>lein</executable>
    <commandlineArgs>install</commandlineArgs>
    <workingDirectory>../nrepl-clojure</workingDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This should just work. What is the MVN command used ? Maybe this config is specified in pluginManagement section, or in a specific profile.

Comment: "mvn install". At what stage does the compile happen -- is it before or after the dependencies are downloaded?

Comment: Compile happens after initialize anyway. What is the output of a 'mvn initialize' command? And what is your project packaging?